# How to generate barcode image in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, barcode

How can I print a barcode image with CodeIgniter?

Do I have to make a custom library or helper to generate a barcode image? Does anyone know any library or helper to generate a barcode image in CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This thread](https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/235473/) on the CodeIgniter forum suggests using the [Zend Barcode class](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.barcode.creation.html). From that thread:

```
function barcode()
{
    $this->load->library('zend');
    $this->zend->load('Zend/Barcode');

    Zend_Barcode::render('code39', 'image', array('text' => 'CodeIgniter Rocks'), array());
}
```

Comment: Thanks colin, Ya it worked but do we have library or a helper in codeigniter.

Comment: @Sujeet: I'm glad it worked, though I'm not sure what you mean about a library or a helper *in* CodeIgniter. It's pretty common to place 3rd party classes/libraries/etc inside of a CodeIgniter implementation, hence the `third_party` and `libraries` directories.